# Rotate line labels in Lattice

Tags: r, plot, lattice

I would like to rotate the label of a line representing a specific value on a distribution. Please consider the following data as example. It represents the results of a hypothetical test for 1000 students:

```
 e5a <- seq(30, 110, length = 1000)
 e5b <- dnorm(e5a, 70, 10)
```

I draw a plot, and on this plot I would indicate the result of Bob, that is 80:

```
plot_e5a <- xyplot(e5b ~ e5a, 
              type = "l",
              main = "Bob's score",
              panel = function(x, ...){
                      panel.xyplot(x, ...)
                      panel.abline(v = c(70, 80), lty = c(1, 2))
                      panel.text(lab = c("Mean", "Bob"), x = c(70, 80), y = 0.037, 
            adj = c(0.4, 0), cex = 1.5)
              })
```

[image]

I would like to rotate the labels "mean" and "bob" on the two vertical lines of the graph, hence I tried to rotate the text with the argument **rot**, that I usually use for [Lattice plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11910353/how-to-rotate-the-x-axis-labels-90-degrees-in-levelplot):

```
panel.text(lab = c("Mean", "Bob"), x = c(70, 80), y = 0.037, 
            adj = c(0.4, 0), cex = 1.5, rot = 90)
```

Unfortunately, it had no effect. I tried **las** too, without effect.

Comment: Are you looking for the `srt` argument? For example: `panel.text(lab = c("Mean", "Bob"), x = c(70, 80), y = 0.037, adj = c(0.4, 0), cex = 1.5, srt = 90)`

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you. Can you suggest me a resource to learn the difference between `rot`, `srt`, that is, when should I use the first or the second.

Comment: The help page for [`?xyplot`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/lattice/html/xyplot.html) has information about `rot` which is passed in a list to the `scales` argument.  It is the "Angle (in degrees) by which the axis labels are to be rotated."  `srt` is a little harder to track down, but you can find information about it by starting with `?panel.text`, which will tell you to look to the corresponding base function `text`, which points to the graphical parameters help page: [`?par`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/par.html)